# ProFTPD killed (signal 15) error - how to fix logrotate restart error?

Tags: cron, logrotate, proftpd

ProFTPD on Ubuntu is being killed unexpectedly.

Log message:

```
$ tail /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log.1
...
... ProFTPD killed (signal 15)
... ProFTPD 1.3.5rc3 standalone mode SHUTDOWN
```

Diagnosis: the time of the message is the same time that `cron` runs the `logrotate` command.

Google searches turn up various info about ProFTPD having a glitch on Debian-based systems due to log files, log rotations, and the ProFTPD server not restarting.

I will add a bounty for a solution to this. I've posted a workaround answer too, in case it's helpful for others.

Comment: Cross-reference: http://askubuntu.com/q/469467/11316

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here's a workaround solution thanks to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/proftpd-dfsg/+bug

The problem is due to ProFTPD not stopping in time to be restarted.

The workaround is to edit the service file, to add a retry.

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd
```

Find this line:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --signal $SIGNAL --quiet --pidfile "$PIDFILE"
```

Change to this:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --signal $SIGNAL --retry 1 --quiet --pidfile "$PIDFILE"
```

This change solved it for me.

Suggestions for improvements are most welcome.

Comment: As I read comments in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/proftpd-dfsg/+bug/1246245, its better to remove sleep 1 to avoid race condition. So it will become:  start-stop-daemon --stop --signal $SIGNAL --retry 1 --quiet --pidfile "$PIDFILE"

Comment: @digz6666 Thanks, that's good new info; I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Years passed, and that bug is still there. It's craaaazy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be having a password protected certificate then the service fails when automatically restarted w/o human intervention.

read here.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=816156